# How to create a debug configuration for a specific .go file in VSCode?

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, debugging, vscode-debugger

Currently, one must focus the `.go` file to debug in the editor first, then start debugging by pressing F5 key.

What I would like, is to be able to press F5 to start debugging, but without having to focus `main.go` first in the editor.

This is the stock configuration generated by VSCode, one must focus `.go` file before F5:

```
    {
        "name": "Launch Package",
        "type": "go",
        "request": "launch",
        "mode": "auto",
        "program": "${fileDirname}",
    }
```

Tried to specify `program` and `cwd` to make it happy:

```
    {
        "name": "Launch Package",
        "type": "go",
        "request": "launch",
        "mode": "auto",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/cmd/sym_dump/main.go",
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/cmd/sym_dump",
    }
```

That doesn't work however, it complains of non-found functions:

```
Starting: C:\Users\aybe\go\bin\dlv.exe dap --listen=127.0.0.1:49541 from C:\GitHub\psx_mnd_sym/cmd/sym_dump
DAP server listening at: 127.0.0.1:49541
Build Error: go build -o C:\GitHub\psx_mnd_sym\cmd\sym_dump\__debug_bin2780105186.exe -gcflags all=-N -l .\main.go
# command-line-arguments
.\main.go:340:13: undefined: dumpTypes
.\main.go:344:14: undefined: dumpSourceFiles
.\main.go:348:14: undefined: dumpDecls
.\main.go:357:13: undefined: dumpTypes
.\main.go:365:13: undefined: dumpIDAScripts
.\main.go:380:13: undefined: dumpTypes (exit status 1)
```

The actual functions are in another `.go` file in the same directory as `program`.

Both files have `package main` specified on top of them.

How can one create a debug configuration for a specific `.go` file in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the `program` property as a directory instead:

```json
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Launch Package",
      "type": "go",
      "request": "launch",
      "mode": "auto",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/cmd/sym_dump"
    }
  ]
}
```

`${fileDirname}` is [the current opened file's folder path](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference#_predefined-variables). There is a reason that the default `Launch Package` template uses `${fileDirname}` instead of `${file}` (which is used by the `Launch file` template).

Let's see the [doc](https://github.com/go-delve/delve/blob/master/Documentation/usage/dlv_debug.md#synopsis) for `dlv debug` first:

> #### Synopsis
>
> ...
>
> By default, with no arguments, Delve will compile the 'main' package in the current directory, and begin to debug it. Alternatively you can specify a package name and Delve will compile that package instead, and begin a new debug session.
>
> ```
> dlv debug [package] [flags]
> ```

There is not much information about `package`. Let's turn to the [doc](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Compile_and_run_Go_program) for `go run`:

> #### Compile and run Go program
>
> Usage:
>
> ```
> go run [build flags] [-exec xprog] package [arguments...]
> ```
>
> Run compiles and runs the named main Go package. **Typically the package is specified as a list of .go source files from a single directory, but it may also be an import path, file system path, or pattern matching a single known package**, as in 'go run .' or 'go run my/cmd'.

If we specify the `program` property as `${workspaceFolder}/cmd/sym_dump/main.go`, it means that the package contains a single file (`main.go`). But the fact is that the package contains another files that defines `dumpTypes`, `dumpSourceFiles`, etc. That's why it failed to build the program.

BTW, since "The program folder is used as the working directory if cwd is omitted or empty" (see [Launch.json attributes](https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/wiki/debugging#launchjson-attributes)), so you don't need to set the `cwd` property.